# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in Chrome while using Overrides

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to test some features in a production environment, and to achieve this I'm using Google Chrome overrides, that basically allows you to substitute a remote file with a local file.

It sometimes works, but after a couple of reloads it stops working and all the requests start failing, receiving this error in console:

[image]

Pay attention: **I'm not talking of the full page warning that you see when you access an untrusted website, which has the same error code. I'm talking about the error in console which makes the website unusable**.

I say this because I [tried googling](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message) the error and I only see articles about the warning, that you can easily skip. This is a different subject.

What I tried so far, without success is:

- Start chrome with the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag
- Enabling the `allow-insecure-localhost` flag in `chrome://flags`

But they didn't help. How can I tell Chrome to ignore the (inexistent) certificate?

Thank you

---

#### Edit

I add an image of my override configuration:

[image]

`to-override` is my local folder. Then I just clicked on a file in the `source` tab and selected `save for override`. I found the file in my local folder and I changed it. Changes are applied the first time, but on refresh everything stops working and all the requests fail.

My Chrome version is

> 71.0.3578.98 - stable - 64 bit

Comment: Are you positive that the missing resource is the one for which you're serving an override (e.g. the right-hand-side of the console should show)? Can you share the screenshot of your override configuration? Which version of Chrome?

Comment: @EricLaw yes, the missing resource is the one for which I'm service an override, but it's not the only failing! The not-overriden requests fail too. I updated the question adding the information that you required. Thank you for the interest

Comment: Ps. I know you work in fiddler, great product, congratulation :D I successfully used it on Windows. But on MacOS there is no way to start it (it's still in beta, I guess)

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't reproduce this in a simple test-- does the Network tab show the requests? If you navigate the top level page (without the override) and accept the invalid certificate, then retry, does the error go away? Is there any difference in Chrome Canary?